# jquery date picker in views exposed filter changes the date values

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a node type "tasks" and created a view so that current logged in user can see his/her assigned tasks. I have used a "time ago" formatter in the field "deadline" which shows the remaining time to the deadline correctly. I have also created a filter for "deadline" and expose this filter. The selected options are as follows

[image]

The filter is correctly working if I choose "Select" in "Date selection form element" under settings for the "deadline" filter as can be seen below

[image]

[image]

However, when I change the "Date selection form element" to either "Plain" or "Popup", the duration in "Due In" field changes by a day that means if today is 5th March and the task is due on 6th March 2014 by 14:00, the "Due In" field will show 13 hours xx minutes (see image below)

[image]

I really don't understand what is the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue (bug) of Views. You can find details here: [Exposed grouped filter for date not working](https://drupal.org/node/1876168).